# Get coordinates of cursor in JChart2D

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jchart2d

I'm using JChart2D for trace a values of a double array. I'm using `ZoomableChart` and I want get coordinates (x, y) of cursor when this stay over `ZoomableChart` in my code to show them in a `JLabel` and draw a vertical line.

- How can I get the coordinates of the cursor?
- How can I draw this line?

Comment: *"and draw a vertical line. "*  Do you want the line to appear over the chart?

Answer (score 3):

To get a point is easy.  Add a [`MouseMotionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) to the [`ZoomableChart`](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/docs/javadoc/info/monitorenter/gui/chart/ZoomableChart.html).

I'm guessing you want this information to represent a point in the **data in the chart,** rather than in the potentially zoomed `ZoomableChart` component itself.  For that you'll need to look to something like (trawling through the docs for a class I heard of 'today'..) [`Chart2D.getPointFinder()`](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/docs/javadoc/info/monitorenter/gui/chart/Chart2D.html#getPointFinder%28%29), the finder apparently offers [`getNearestPoint(MouseEvent,Chart2D)`](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/docs/javadoc/info/monitorenter/gui/chart/IPointFinder.html#getNearestPoint%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent,%20info.monitorenter.gui.chart.Chart2D%29) to map a `MouseEvent` back to the underlying structure.

Go for it!  :)

Comment: Do you want to link to the JavaDocs for the method in question, or is hitting Google merely part of the 'fun' of helping you?  Also, I asked you a question in a comment.  Since this is not a help desk, and I am not your paid servant, could you pretend like this is a technical site and *answer* my question?  Also, feel free to drop the leading upside down '?' for sentences.  It is not used in English.  (I admire people's efforts to communicate with me in the only language I know, but it helps if they use the common way of writing it.)