# how to get cursor coordinates when it is on Chart2D (jchart2D library)

Tags: java, swing, jchart2d

I'm using jchart2D library to plot functions. I need to get cursor coordinates. [That question was asked already here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469775/get-coordinates-of-cursor-in-jchart2d). When I add MouseMotionListener to Chart2D, it gives location of cursor in pixels (but not coordinates). getNearestPoint function also doesn't work because it finds Point which is in Trace

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that you want to *interpolate* between points on the chart, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20097308/230513). Instead, use a `ChartMouseListener`, as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107935/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894894/230513).

Comment: I guess it works for jfreechart library. But unfortunately I didn't find any analog of CharMouseListener in jchart2d.

Comment: Oops, sorry. You'll need to do linear interpolation, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901472/230513). Are you using `net.sourceforge.chart2d.Chart2D` or `info.monitorenter.gui.chart.Chart2D`?

Comment: I am using info.monitorenter.gui.chart.Chart2D. I can't figure out how your link can help me.

Comment: Ah, two different libraries; I've updated the [tag:jchart2d] tag. You'll have to [interpolate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) the mouse coordinates to derive model coordinates, and vice-versa.

Comment: I see. For this I need location of the origin of axes.